# I need to repalce a column with its correspoding MD5 value using unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting-language

This is my code from previous posts, but it's not working with other 
delimited files.

Can you please help me in modifying this below script for any other delimited files?

```
 awk '{
  tmp="echo " $2 " | openssl md5 | cut -f2 -d\" \""
  tmp | getline cksum
   $2=cksum
  print
  }' < sample
```

Comment: RAMESH|~|12345|~|ABCD RAMESH|~|12345|~|

Comment: If this the delimted file i need to replace 2nd column with its corresponding hash value , how can i modify the above script , please advice.

Comment: You can use another delimiter for your `awk` script. Use `-F "|" as your delimiter.

Comment: RAMESH|12345|TEST|HI U|
PRAVAS|67676|TEST|HI U|
PRAVAS|676766|SETT|HI U|

Comment: Im getting out replacing all my delimiter with space .. No idea whats wrong

Comment: RAMESH d577273ff885c3f84dadb8578bb41399 TEST HI U
PRAVAS 3a408343450221a54e66489c8bfc4cfd TEST HI U
PRAVAS cb966e594d6880db177d7bf0abf35b62 SETT

Comment: please suggest whats going on with this

Comment: I don't understand your problem.. You can change the delimiter to space as well..

Comment: the problem is my input file is having pipe (|) delimiter file , when im using the above script its throwing correct output but all the (|) pipe delimiter are getting replaced with space in the out put file.  Ex:: RAM|TEST o/p        RAM d577273ff885 , i need it as RAM|d577273ff885

Comment: please let me know if it is still now clear

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 2 things to your `awk` script:

1. The `-F` parameter which you can set your input delimiter by, and set it to pipe (|)
2. the `-v OPS` parameter which set the output delimiter from the default space to your desired one (e.g pipe)

Try this code:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{
  tmp="echo " $2 " | openssl md5 | cut -f2 -d\" \""
  tmp | getline cksum
   $2=cksum
  print
  }' < sample
```